# Inserting at top of richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Whats wrong with this code? Trying to get my text to insert at the beginning of the textbox rather than at the bottom.

```
private void execute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  startFinshBox.Text = "Start Time: " + printTime()+"";
  startFinshBox.Text.Insert(0,printTime()+": Retrieving Results...\n");
}
```

But it will not insert the second line into the rtb. I have tried with startFinishBox.SelectionStart = 0 as well, and it made no difference. Am I missing something else?

Thanks, Psy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`startFinshBox.Text` is a string, which is an immutable type in C#. `string.Insert()` will return the modified string as a result, but it your code you discard it. To make it work, you have to change the code to:

```
private void execute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  startFinshBox.Text = "Start Time: " + printTime()+"";
  startFinshBox.Text = startFinshBox.Text.Insert(0,printTime()+": Retrieving Results...\n");
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I knew it would have been something simple like that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectionStart` property on a TextBox  will determine *where* text will be selected or inserted from.

Use this code to insert code at the start of the text box control:

```
TextBox.SelectionStart = 0;
TextBox.SelectedText = "Start time: " + printTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

ShowText inserts a new Line at top of the RichTextBox.
Invoke enables you to call it from another thread.
LineLimit removes the last line after the LineLimit is reached.
If you add the RichTextBox_ContentsResized eventhandler to your control, its adjusting its size automatically.

```
    public bool? ShowText(string pText)
    {
        try
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
                return Invoke(new Func<string, bool?>(ShowText), pText) as bool?;

            rtbRemoteControl.Text = rtbRemoteControl.Text.Insert(0, $"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss} - {pText}\n");

            var lLineCount = rtbRemoteControl.Lines.Length;
            const int lLineLimit = 500;
            if (lLineCount > lLineLimit)
                rtbRemoteControl.Lines = rtbRemoteControl.Lines.Take(lLineCount - 1).ToArray();
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void RichTextBox_ContentsResized(object pSender, ContentsResizedEventArgs e)
    {
        const int margin = 5;
        var lSender = pSender as RichTextBox;
        if (lSender == null)
            return;
        lSender.ClientSize = new Size(e.NewRectangle.Width + margin,  e.NewRectangle.Height + margin);
    }
```