# RichTextBox new Text append on top

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `RichtTextBox` in my `C#` application that shows a log to the user. The problem is that newly inserted text `appends` below the old text, but I want to `append` it on top of the old text.

For example, When I append the text "Newtext" it looks like this:

`RichtTextBox`:

```
|---------------------
|Oldtext             |
|Newtext             |
|---------------------
```

But it needs to look like this:

`RichTextBox`:

```
|---------------------
|Newtext             |
|Oldtext             |
|---------------------
```

This is the code I'm using for filling my `RichTextBox`:

```
public void DisplayLog(string logtext)
        {
            if (logtext != "")
            {
                if (this.txtLog.InvokeRequired && !txtLog.IsDisposed)
                {
                    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                        {
                            txtLog.AppendText(DateTime.UtcNow + ": " + logtext + "\n");
                        }));
                }
                else if (!txtLog.IsDisposed)
                {
                    txtLog.AppendText(DateTime.UtcNow + ": " + logtext + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
```

Can somebody help me out please?

**Answer:**

[Inserting at top of richtextbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818875/inserting-at-top-of-richtextbox)

Comment: Check this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850716/append-text-to-the-beginning-in-the-rich-text-box)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850716/append-text-to-the-beginning-in-the-rich-text-box

Comment: That answer isn't working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Insert

```
txtLog.Text =  txtLog.Text.Insert(0,DateTime.UtcNow + ": " + logtext + "\n");
```

Comment: Hmmm, after using your code, the text won't show up in my RichTextBox anymore.

Comment: Correct it works, Just found it out myself using this topic answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818875/inserting-at-top-of-richtextbox

Answer (score 2):

I think txtlog is the RichTextBox and you should prepend this.

To do this go at start using

```
txtlog .SelectionStart = 0;
txtlog .SelectionLength = 0;
txtlog .SelectedText = (DateTime.UtcNow + ": " + logtext + "\n");
```